# An ODE argument of Hitchin

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

In [1] (p. 183, paragraph of Eq. 7.8), Hitchin makes an argument which I would summarize as follows.

> Suppose that $A\in\mathfrak{u}(n)$ (a skew-Hermitian matrix) has distinct eigenvalues and let $S:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathfrak{u}(n)$ be a real analytic map in a neighbourhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, the ordinary differential equation
>   $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{iA}{t}x+iS(t)x,\quad \text{where } x:(0,\epsilon)\to\mathbb{C}^n,$$
>   has a basis of solutions $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ such that $t^{-\lambda_i}x_i\to v_i$ as $t\to 0$, where $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is a basis of eigenvectors for $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$.

**Question:** Can someone explain why this is true?

It might be useful to add that $A$ actually comes from an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, i.e. $A=\rho(\begin{smallmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{smallmatrix})$ where $\rho:\mathfrak{su}(2)\to\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the representation.

I thought at first that the trick would be to set $y:=t^{-\lambda_1}x_1v_1+\cdots+t^{-\lambda_n}x_nv_n$ and try to reduce the problem into a standard first order linear ODE with no poles. However, the $v_i$s are not necessarily eigenvectors of $S$ so we still get factors $t^{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}$ for all $i,j$.

---

**Reference**

[1] N. J. Hitchin, *On the construction of monopoles.* Commun. Math. Phys. 89, 145-190 (1983)

Comment: If you make the substitution $s=\log t$, then $\frac{dx}{ds}=t\frac{dx}{dt}$. This removes the pole. Now this is roughly a question of finding a normal form for an ODE near a fixed point. Not quite because the right side is not time-independent. Presumably if you dig into those arguments, you should be able to extract a proof.